Trouble using equals in prisma with number type
I have this model
model Model {
id                         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
clientNumber               Int

And I want to execute an update where the clientNumber is in an Array of values. I tried to use the in argument, but I have the same error.
const listOfNumber: number[] = [1,2,3];
await prisma.model.update({
  where: {
    clientNumber: {
       in: [listOfNumbers]
    }
  },
  data: {
    ...
  }
})

Type '{ clientNumber: { equals: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ModelWhereUniqueInput'

